# When I add a wall using archipack it comes without the default materials

Tags: archipack-add-on

Normally when you add a wall using Archipack, it comes with a few default materials (like inside, outside, cuts, etc.), but now when I add a wall there are no materials.

In console I get this message:

```
archipack: unable to add material DEFAULT for wall2
```

It happens only with walls. Windows, doors, roofs work as expected.

I tried deleting and downloading blender again but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: what is your blender version?

Comment: The version is 2.91.0

Comment: did you try other versions? Which one worked?

Comment: I didn't try other versions. It worked on this one. I was changing things in Archipack prefrences so maybe that messed it up, but i'm not sure as I am pretty convinced that I returned everything how it originally was.

Comment: maybe there is a factory reset for those as well. I am not sure how archipack handles its preferences, but try to do a factory reset of blender and open a clean new session

Comment: It worked. I didn't reset whole blender first time. Thank you!

Comment: have a good new year ;)

Comment: Have a good new year too!